# Get type of construct function in Typescript interface

Tags: typescript, constructor

Given a Typescript interface:

```
interface Foo {
    bar(a: string): Bar
}
```

I can get the type of a function by indexing into the interface type:

```
type X = Foo["bar"] // X is (a: string) => Bar
```

But this doesn't work with a construct signature:

```
interface Foo {
    new(a: string): Bar
}

type X = Foo["new"] // Property 'new' does not exist on type 'Foo'
```

Is there a way to access this type (really just the return type, `Bar`)? I hacked together this, but I'm sure there's a better way:

```
const foo: Foo
const inst = new foo('')
type X = typeof inst // Bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript added a type called `InstanceType` for this case with version 2.8.

```
interface Foo {
    new(a: string): Bar
}

type X = InstanceType<Foo>; // Bar
```